# How to change the menu classes in Joomla 3 default.php file to mimic custom menu classes

Tags: php, joomla, menu, zurb-foundation

Ok the background on this is as follows: 
1.  I want the joomla menu nav to switch from its default classes to my custom classes and add an  tag for the pages active menu item (if neccessary)

The default classes in the default.php file is this

```
<ul class="nav menu<?php echo $class_sfx;?>"<?php
$tag = '';

if ($params->get('tag_id') != null)
{
    $tag = $params->get('tag_id') . '';
    echo ' id="' . $tag . '"';
}
 ?>>
 <?php
 foreach ($list as $i => &$item)
 {
$class = 'item-' . $item->id;

if ($item->id == $active_id)
{
    $class .= ' current';
}

if (in_array($item->id, $path))
{
    $class .= ' active';
}
elseif ($item->type == 'alias')
{
    $aliasToId = $item->params->get('aliasoptions');

    if (count($path) > 0 && $aliasToId == $path[count($path) - 1])
    {
        $class .= ' active';
    }
    elseif (in_array($aliasToId, $path))
    {
        $class .= ' alias-parent-active';
    }
}

if ($item->type == 'separator')
{
    $class .= ' divider';
}

if ($item->deeper)
{
    $class .= ' deeper';
}

if ($item->parent)
{
    $class .= ' parent';
}

if (!empty($class))
{
    $class = ' class="' . trim($class) . '"';
}

echo '<li' . $class . '>';

// Render the menu item.
switch ($item->type) :
    case 'separator':
    case 'url':
    case 'component':
    case 'heading':
        require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_' .                                                 $item->type);
        break;

    default:
        require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'default_url');
        break;
endswitch;

// The next item is deeper.
if ($item->deeper)
{
    echo '<ul class="nav-child unstyled small">';
}
elseif ($item->shallower)
{
    // The next item is shallower.
    echo '</li>';
    echo str_repeat('</ul></li>', $item->level_diff);
}
else
{
    // The next item is on the same level.
    echo '</li>';
}
 }
 ?></ul>
```

the output via browser is this

```
<ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/">Home</a></li></ul>
```

the output I would like it to be is this...

```
 <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
    <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

My brute intution would tell me to change the nav to title-area but I am unsure of how to incorporate "name" into the li structure.

Moreover, I am assuming the  tag is only for the page that is active or present at the moment... This would be nice to incorporate as well... as my foundation css structure has the line height already assigned to that structure of html.

help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand the basic concept of a layout override? All you need to do is copy that file and add it to your template in the right folder and you can modify it as you wish. I'm not sure what your question is about adding name to the class ... just type name.  If you really want it on every menu link just say `$class = 'name   item-' . $item->id;`  I wouldn't recommend removing the other classes whcih give you a lot of customization power.

Comment: @Elin I am building a template. I removed the classes that were there because I am not using them.  It would be nice to build a plugin to alter the or something but that is the reasoning behind it.  Effectively I did what your suggestion was.

Comment: Right so you just did an override. I just think you are future proofing to leave in the classes that let you modify highly specific items based on their IDs.  It would be reasonable to allow a style to be added to the `<li>` just as when you make a menu item you can currently add a style for the `<a>` but really, for a serious template I think you want to be doing it the way you are since you can have total control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after testing I have figured out the proper answer.  Now this solution is in general and should work well for any menu and dropdown menu structure within Joomla's default menu system.

I have complete this solution with Foundation 5 menu setup (later I will try a different menu system but the idea should be the same).

For the menu module go to the default.php located here: /modules/mod_menu/tmpl

The default setting has a class structure of nav menu as such:

```
<ul class="nav menu<?php echo $class_sfx;?>"<?php
$tag = '';
```

Change the class to be what you need the class structure to be.  if you are 100% circumventing the Joomla css (bootstrap) file structure then you can change it... or if not you can just add a class name(s) that you need.

here is what mine changed to:

```
<ul class="right nav menu<?php echo $class_sfx;?>"<?php
$tag = '';
```

Now if you are following your new menu system's class structure (Foundation) you might need to designate a class for `<li` and for the sub menu items i.e. for a dropdown menu.

***Keep in mind that for Joomla's menu structure within PHP it pulls the item number and if it is the current page it will auto mark it as auto (automatically)... so no need to add that in except for the class you are adding.  Edit* Adding the class "has-dropdown" should be for the parent

so on this line (the before):

```
if ($item->parent)
{
    $class .= ' parent';
}
```

Change it to this (the after):

```
if ($item->parent)
{
    $class .= ' has-dropdown parent';
}
```

As well the sub child items need to change.

So on this line (the before):

```
// The next item is deeper.
if ($item->deeper)
{
 echo '<ul class="nav-child unstyled small">';
}
```

Change it to this (the after):

```
// The next item is deeper.
if ($item->deeper)
{
    echo '<ul class="dropdown nav-child unstyled small">';
}
```

I think it would be great to add a plug-in that can mod the backend menu setup to include class to add to or change for `<ul` and `<li` for both menu and sub menu child items.

Hopefully this helps someone... I will add more later.

*I have one error I am getting with this and the Foundation menu I am using.  The first child will show but if that child has a child menu item it won't show... So there's that fix still needed.

*remember to change the setting: Show Sub-menu Items to "yes"

Comment: There are already options in all of the menu modules that let you add classes specifically for menus in addition to the classes all modules have. It may not be enough for you but you might try just using the menu class suffix parameter, leaving a space at the beginning if you aren't modifying the current class.

Comment: @Elin correct me if I am wrong but adding a class to the class suffix parameter won't necessarily give me the control over the <ul vs <li class placement.  Are you speaking about this option right here?  <ul class="nav menu<?php echo $class_sfx;?>  so if I add a class in the class suffix parameter it will go there.  That is for the <ul how about the <li for the parent menu item... can I add <li and the ?php echo $class_sfx;?> <<<

Comment: Yes the menu one goes on the ul no the li.  So you probably just want to add that in a layout override for the menu module and add that echo or a hard coded class name.  I wouldn't take anything out just add it to the first or last step of building the class string.

Comment: @Elin are you talking about the page class suffix because that is not working it just goes to a div on the page.

Comment: No, I'm saying you can override the module layout and add your class to it in the appropriate place, which I would say is in that part of the code where it is building the class for the <li> tags. It's doing a complex job, marking the levels and whether it is active and also with  unique number so I would not throw htat out, I'd add yours to the string.

Comment: @Elin I get what you're saying.  i am going to make a couple of adjustments as that <li item needs to be on the "parent" structure.  As well I am going to add the nav menu back in because of what you are saying.

Comment: So this works pretty good.  one thing I don't like about the foundation menu and it is probably some other adjustments I need to make is how the mobile menu works for this.  But that is another issue.  If I have more info I will keep up with this post.  links are how they should be.  Now it would be cool to create a plugin so this doesn't have to be so brutish of a hack.

Comment: @Elin I have one error and I figured out what is going on.  When I have a menu item setup as Parent > child >> child of child.  So Menu then hover and Page 2 and Hover on Page 2 then Page 3 shows.  Well when I am on the home page the page 3 child never shows.  The code is never there in the html... However when I go to page 2 then the code appears and page 3 will show.  Does this make sense?  Is this Joomla or Foundation doing this?

Comment: There are settings in your menu module that determine how many sublevels to display.

Comment: @Elin You are AWESOME... Thanks.  This fixed it.  Show Sub-menu Items
 set to yes.  it would be nice to label the submenus with the <lable> tag my framework uses.  I am going to now try this with jetmenu and see what i come up with.  I think I like that menu system better than foundations.  if it comes down to the similar changes I will definitely create a plugin for this.